# How to fix overlapped status bar which mess with child view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, ios7, uistatusbar

I am making a sliding menu. But when I slide-open and slide close, the front view controller's navigation bar overlaps with system status bar.

[image]

```
if (should_hide_status_bar)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:is_going_to_open withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimationSlide)];
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:2 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:(0) animations:^
{
    CGFloat             disp0   =   state == AASlideViewControllerSlidingStateClose ? 0 : OPEN_X_POS;
    CGAffineTransform   t1      =   CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(disp0, 0);

    self.frontViewController.view.transform =   t1;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    self->_flags.is_sliding             =   NO;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled    =   YES;
}];
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you are setting the status bar visibility out of the animation block. Move it into the animation block and we'll see it's working correctly.

```
BOOL const      should_hide_status_bar  =   _shouldHideStatusBarWhenOpen;
BOOL const      is_going_to_open        =   state == AASlideViewControllerSlidingStateOpen;

[UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:2 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:(0) animations:^
{
    CGFloat             disp0   =   state == AASlideViewControllerSlidingStateClose ? 0 : OPEN_X_POS;
    CGAffineTransform   t1      =   CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(disp0, 0);

    self.frontViewController.view.transform =   t1;

    if (should_hide_status_bar)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:is_going_to_open withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimationSlide)];
    }
}
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    self->_flags.is_sliding             =   NO;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled    =   YES;
}];
```

[image]